# Am I not using rpart() right for classification?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do an example classification prediction with `rpart()` but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to be giving me the right predictions when I pass test data into a fitted tree.

```
library(rpart)
data.samples <- sample(1:nrow(cu.summary), nrow(cu.summary) * 0.7, replace = FALSE)
training.data <- cu.summary[data.samples, ]
test.data <- cu.summary[-data.samples, ]

fit <- rpart(
  Type~Price + Country + Reliability + Mileage, 
   method="class",
  data=training.data
  )

fit.pruned<- prune(fit, cp=fit$cptable[which.min(fit$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])

prediction <- predict(fit.pruned, test.data)
prediction

#table(prediction, test.data$Type)
```

This seems to give me everything *except* the classes I was trying to predict in the first place. Am I using a particular syntax wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the type of prediction

```
predict(fit.pruned, test.data, type="class")
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks, I forgot to add that option to the prediction function.